# How to open PDF report (from report viewer) using ajax in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to print a PDF File from my application (rdlc report). So I need to display the file in the browser without downloading using Ajax. The following code is trying to open the file using `<a>`tag(`<a href="~/.../" target="_blank">print </a>`) but it does not work in the ajax call. Please provide a code sample or instruction in C#.

Here is the generation of the PDF from the report viewer:

```cs
public void CreatePdfFromList(string fileName, string reportpath, ArrayList dsNameArray, ArrayList DTArray)
{
    ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();
    Warning[] warnings = null;
    string[] streamIds = null;
    string mimeType = string.Empty;
    string encoding = string.Empty;
    string extension = string.Empty;
    string filetype = string.Empty;

    viewer.SizeToReportContent = true;
    viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = reportpath;
    viewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;

    for (int i = 0; i < dsNameArray.Count; i++)
    {
        ReportDataSource rds1 = new ReportDataSource((string)dsNameArray[i], (IEnumerable)DTArray[i]);
        viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds1);
    }

    viewer.LocalReport.Refresh();

    byte[] pdfContent = viewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);

    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = mimeType;
    //Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + "." + extension);
    Response.BinaryWrite(pdfContent);
    //Response.Flush(); // send it to the client to download
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.End();
}
```

and here is the ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/.../",
         data: {...},
         success: function (json) {
         //window.open(json);
         //open file i think...
         }
         })
```

When trying to show pdf content I use console.log(json). It shows me the string but the content appears like this:

```
�~�
```

Comment: Does something simple work, like a JavaScript new Window (popup) that navigates to the code to generate the PDF? I see your Ajax is incomplete but the PDF generation code is key

Comment: You need the header

Comment: but if i activate the header it will download the file and that not i want  @bradbury9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ajax

```
function openpdf()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("OpenPDF", "TrangChu")',
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                 let pdfWindow = window.open("");
            pdfWindow.document.write("<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='data:application/pdf;base64," + data + "'></iframe>");

            }
        });
    }
```

In View

```
  <button onclick="openpdf()">Open PDF</button>
```

In Controller

```
 string strAttachment = Server.MapPath(@"/Reports/haha.pdf");
 byte[] renderdByte = lr.Render("Pdf", "", out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streams, out warnings);
             string base64EncodedPDF = System.Convert.ToBase64String(renderdByte);
        return Json(base64EncodedPDF, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: thank you for answer... but  my file did not saved before, so i wand to open the file in browser  after generate the report but your code here is to open the file that been saved before

Comment: i just searched and edited, hope this will help you.